# How to make a Data Pipeline from MQTT to KAFKA Broker to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

How can I make a data pipeline, I am sending data from MQTT to KAFKA topic using Source Connector. and on the other side, I have also connected Kafka Broker to MongoDB using Sink Connector. I am having trouble making a data pipeline that goes from MQTT to KAFKA and then MongoDB. Both connectors are working properly individually. How can I integrate them?

here is my MQTT Connector

[MQTT Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoatZ.jpg)

[Node 1 MQTT Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9q4w.png)

[Message Published from MQTT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IywoT.png)

[Kafka Consumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGuwC.png)

[Node 2 MongoDB Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3c1V.png)

[MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApnrW.png)

that is my MongoDB Connector

[MongoDB Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJkiA.jpg)

Comment: What are the logs and configuration of connectors? are you using connectors in distributed mode?

Comment: @AchyutVyas I have made kafka cluster and running them on standalone mode.

Comment: please also post the worker configuration.

Comment: @AchyutVyas which configuration If u can tell me so I can post.
Thanks for ur reply

Comment: Kafka-connect and Kafka-connector's workers' configurations for both MQTT source and MongoDB Sink.

Comment: @AchyutVyas kindly check I have updated

Comment: What errors are you experiencing? So the data goes from your MQTT to kafka topic? And data from kafka topic goes to MongoDB ? So what the issue? Where is your problem?

Comment: @RanLupovich both connectors are working. but I want to make a data pipeline. Data is going to kafka topic but I don't kow how to send that data which is received on Kafka Broker to MongoDB may be I don't know how to use Kafka Connect. Basically I am having a problem in integration. If u can guide I would be thankful.

Comment: @RanLupovich you seem to be a Kafka expert. I am eagerly waiting for your reply.

Comment: @RanLupovich let me try to exlplain you more precisely my query. 
The message which I am sending from MQTT is not receiving at MongoDb. The message is limited to the Kafka Consumer. Through Kafka Publisher I can publish my message to MongoDB as my connector is working.  although I am using the same topic but still don't know.

Comment: @RanLupovich I have made a Kafka Cluster in which there are two Nodes. one for mqtt and one for mongodb. I am running them on standalone mode. I am adding more ss so you can understand.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "creating data pipeline" - what are you expecting?

Comment: Please add codes instead of screenshots

Comment: @RanLupovich my data go from MQTT to MongoDB through Kafka Connect.

Comment: You need both connectors to share same kafka cluster, what does node1 and node2 mean is it seperate kafka instance? Your connector need to connect to the same kafka node in order to share the data inside the kafka topic one for input and one for output, share your bootstrap service parameters,  share your server.properties as well of the kafka

Comment: @RanLupovich okay I got some point...actually when I was trying to run both connectors in one node. they were not working. Only one connector is running at a time in a single node. So I made two nodes/ Maybe I made a mistake in this. one node is listening to 9092 and second one is 9093. What should I do now?

Comment: In order to run two different connect clusters inside same kafka , you need to set in different internal topics for each connect cluster

config.storage.topic
offset.storage.topic
status.storage.topic

Comment: Share the error when trying to run both connectors on same kafka node

Comment: @RanLupovich Thank you for your feedback. I just sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what exactly the problem is without more logs, please provide your connect.config as well, please check /status of your connector, I still did not understand exactly what the issue you are facing, you are saying that , MQTT SOURCE CONNECTOR sending messages successfully to KAFKA TOPIC and your MONGO DB SINK CONNECTOR successfully reading this KAFKA TOPIC and write to your mobgodb, hence your pipeline, Where is the error? Is your KAFKA is the same KAFKA? Or separated different KAFKA CLUSTERS? Seems like both localhost, but is it the same machine?

Please elaborate and explain what are you expecting? What does "pipeline" means in your word?

You need both connectors to share same kafka cluster, what does node1 and node2 mean is it seperate kafka instance? Your connector need to connect to the same kafka "node" / cluster in order to share the data inside the kafka topic one for input and one for output, share your bootstrap service parameters,  share your server.properties as well of the kafka

In order to run two different connect clusters inside same kafka , you need to set in different internal topics for each connect cluster

```
config.storage.topic
offset.storage.topic
status.storage.topic
```